# Grease Pencil Vertex Problem

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I've recently gotten into Grease Pencil animation on Blender v2.79 but whenever I try to select the whole grease pencil frame to position the drawing elsewhere, the drawing only selects a single vertex to pull out when I want to move the whole object.

[image]

Like so....

[image]

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? I would greatly appreciate any help, I have looked on youtube vids and they never seem to have this problem. Thanks!

- Gemma

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already solved this by now, but it looks like you're in "Edit" mode.  Try selecting the drawing in "Object" mode (by hitting <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), then try moving it.